# Exercise 3.4 in Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am self-learning algebraic topology by reading Rotman's An Introduction to Algebraic Topology. I am stuck on Exercise 3.4 on page 41. I'd be grateful for any hints or solution.

Exercise 3.4:

Let $\sigma:\Delta^2 \to X$ be continuous, where $\Delta^2=[e_0,e_1,e_2]$.
Define $\varepsilon_0:I \to \Delta^2$ as the affine map with
$\varepsilon_0(0)=e_1$ and $\varepsilon_0(1)=e_2$; similarly,
define $\varepsilon_1$ by $\varepsilon_1(0)=e_0$ and
$\varepsilon_1(1)=e_2$, and define $\varepsilon_2$ by $\varepsilon_2(0)=e_0$
and $\varepsilon_2(1)=e_1$. Finally, define $\sigma_i=\sigma \circ \varepsilon_i$ for $i=0,1,2$.

1. Prove that $(\sigma_0 \ast \sigma_1^{-1}) \ast \sigma_2$
   is null homotopic rel $\{0,1\}$.
2. Prove that $(\sigma_1 \ast \sigma_0^{-1}) \ast \sigma_2^{-1}$
   is null homotopic rel $\{0,1\}$.
3. Let $F:I \times I \to X$ be continuous, and define paths
   $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ in $X$ by
   $\alpha(t)=F(t,0),
   \beta(t)=F(t,1),
   \gamma(t)=F(0,t)
   $,
   and
   $\delta(t)=F(1,t)$.
   Prove that $\alpha \simeq \gamma \ast \beta \ast \delta^{-1}$ rel $\{0,1\}$.

As a hint, Rotman suggests the use of Theorem 1.6, which states that
for a continuous map $f:S^n \to Y$, the following are equvalent:

1. $f$ is nullhomotopic;
2. $f$ can be extended to a continuous map $D^{n+1} \to Y$;
3. if $x_0 \in S^n$ and $k:S^n \to Y$ is the constant map at $f(x_0)$, then 
   there is a  homotopy $F:f \simeq k$ with $F(x_0,t)=f(x_0)$ for all $t \in I$.

I'm not sure how the hint applies to the exercise. Neither do I see how to proceed without the hint. I can write down explicit formulas for 
$\varepsilon_i, i=0,1,2$, but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Comment: Not everyone has immediate access to the book. Please write the full exercise *in your post*, along with what exactly has got you stuck.

Comment: **Hint:** Note that $\Delta^2$ is homotopy equivalent to $D^2$. Use 2. from the theorem.

Comment: In fact, $\Delta^2$ is homeomorphic to $D^2$, right?